# Transpose data with MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a dataset returned from a MS Access SQL query that looks like Table 1.

Table 1

```
Year    Quarter P1  P2
2013    Q1      1   6
2013    Q2      2   9
2013    Q3      5   1
2013    Q4      6   4
2014    Q1      4   3
2014    Q2      8   2
2014    Q3      6   5
2014    Q4      2   4
2015    Q1      2   3
2015    Q2      1   1
```

I would like to transpose the data to look like Table 2.

Table 2

```
Year    Quarter Value   P1
2014    Q3      P1      6
2014    Q3      P2      5
2014    Q4      P1      2
2014    Q4      P2      4
2015    Q1      P1      2
2015    Q1      P2      3
2015    Q2      P1      1
2015    Q2      P2      1
```

I've been looking around internet and understand that I need to use `TRANSPOSE` in the query but I can't figure out how to use it especially since I don't want to transpose the two first columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with `union all`:

```
select year, quarter, 'P1' as value, p1
from table1
union all
select year, quarter, 'P2' as value, p2
from table1;
```

You might want to add `where` clauses to get only the rows in your desired results.